# Struggling with Unzipping A File

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
String mixtapefilename = "testzip.zip";
String zipname = mixtapefilename; 
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";              
        unpackZip(path, zipname);

private boolean unpackZip(String path, String zipname)
{       
     InputStream is;
     ZipInputStream zis;
     try 
     {
         is = new FileInputStream(path + zipname);
         zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));          
         ZipEntry ze;

         while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) 
         {
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
             int count;

             // zapis do souboru
             String filename = ze.getName();
             FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);

             // cteni zipu a zapis
             while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
             {
                 baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                 byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                 fout.write(bytes);             
                 baos.reset();
             }

             fout.close();               
             zis.closeEntry();
         }

         zis.close();
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         toast.show();
     } 
     catch(IOException e)
     {
         ProgressDialog dialog;
         dialog = new ProgressDialog(Download.this);                
         dialog.setMessage(e.toString());
         dialog.show();

         return false;
     }

    return true;
}
```

And my error is: /mnt/sdcard/download/testzip/testzip.mp3 (No such file or directory)

So it can't find my MP3? But it is supposed to be unzipping my mp3, do I somehow need to create the directories first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to create necessary files and directory first before you do unzipping. I believe your sd card already have download directory in it. If so, try this code below. Feel free to adjust to your need.

```
    private boolean unpackZip(String path, String zipname){       
     InputStream is;
     ZipInputStream zis;
     try 
     {
         is = new FileInputStream(path + zipname);
         zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));          
         ZipEntry ze;

         while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) 
         {
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
             int count;

             // zapis do souboru
             String filename = ze.getName();
     File innerFile = new File(path, fileName);

             if (ze.isDirectory()) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "The Entry is a directory..");
        innerFile.mkdirs();
     } else {
             FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);

             // cteni zipu a zapis
             while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
             {
                 baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                 byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                 fout.write(bytes);             
                 baos.reset();
             }

             fout.close();               
             zis.closeEntry();
         }

         zis.close();
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         toast.show();
       }
     } 
     catch(IOException e)
     {
         ProgressDialog dialog;
         dialog = new ProgressDialog(Download.this);                
         dialog.setMessage(e.toString());
         dialog.show();

         return false;
     }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wait is that wrong? We are saying if ze is a directory then make that directory?

Comment: you can remove that part if you are sure there is no directory inside the zip you are downloading/Unzipping. The most important part is creating `File innerFile = new File(path,fileName)`

Comment: ok. I guess it would be because either you don't have download directory on your phone's SD card or you don't have SD card mounted on your phone. 
Make sure your Phone SD card is not mounted to computer and make sure you have download directory on your sd card.

Comment: sd card is on my phone and not mounted and download directory is on the phone already, always has been

Comment: Okay so I know it's because it's not creating the folder that is INSIDE the zip because inside the zip is a testzip folder and then a testzip.mp3 and the folder is not being created. How do I create the folder programmatically without know which folders are going to be in there beforehand?

Comment: it is included in my answer. 
`(if (ze.isDirectory()) {innerFile.mkdirs()}else{..do normal thing..};`

Comment: if ze.isDirectory() is never getting called. Is there a reason it wouldn't count a folder as a directory or something